# Laravel - queue job finished - how to use Queue::after?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I would like to modify a session variable when my queue job has finished. I found in laravel documentation, that Queue::after is created for my issue, but I can not find out how to use it.

I start the job from a controller: VideoController.php

`$job = (new VideoConvertJob($newFileName))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5)); dispatch($job);`

There are some code in the job (VideoConvertJob.php) handle method:

`public function handle() { ... }`

But I do not know, where and how should I imlement the Queue::after method, to know that job has finished succesfully and update my session.